# Adding custom headers using AmqpProxyFactoryBean + AmqpInvokerServiceExporter

Tags: spring-amqp

I have two separate services communicating using `AmqpProxyFactoryBean` (the "client") and `AmqpInvokerServiceExporter` (the "server"). Now, I'd like to include some custom headers on every request made through the AMQP proxy and be able to access them on the "server". Is there any easy way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `AmqpClientInterceptor` uses `AmqpTemplate` to send and receive AMQP messages, you can provide for that `RabbitTemplate` any custom `MessageConverter`. And populate any additional headers from your `toMessage()` implementation.

However I'm not sure that you will be able to access to those custom header on the server side. We end up there just with `RemoteInvocation.invoke()`.

So, seems for me you finally come up to the solution with an additional RPC param.

From other side that custom header may be useful for other AQMP routing scenarios when you can route that RPC message not only to the RPC queue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Spring Integration AMQP Gateways](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html) instead of remoting over rabbitmq; that way you have complete control over the headers passed back and forth.

If you don't want to use Spring Integration, you can use the `RabbitTemplate` `sendAndReceive` methods on the client and either the `receiveAndSend` or a listener container on the server.

Again, this gives you full control over the headers.